# Maven install fails after maven clean in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project in Eclipse and I added some local `jar` files to the buildpath. If I do not add any dependency to the `pom.xml` file I am able to execute `maven install`. Then, if I add those dependencies to the `pom` the command `maven install` continues working as well. Now in this situation if I run `maven clean` then `maven install` fails. Why?

I also tried to run `Maven` -> `Update Project` but the result is the same. What is the problem?

Comment: Can't tell based on what you've posted.  Works fine with IntelliJ.  Maybe you need a better IDE.

Comment: question not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using non maven dependencies then it will fail to build eg from CLI and in your case in Elipse after cleaning the project as well. In order to make it work you have to installl tha `JAR` you are using as Maven artifact and the ninclude it in `POM` dependencies like every other library.

Here you have info on how to install 3rd party JARs to local repo

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and resolved by adding the 3rd party in the pom.xml manually